# NX Cypress run twice on the GitHub Action

Tags: cypress, github-actions, e2e-testing, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am using NX 14.5.1 and cypress 10.2.0. When I run e2e tests on GitHub actions, my tests always run twice. Sometimes one of them causes an error.

This is my github workflow:

```
jobs:
  continuous_integration:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 45
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
      # run copies of the current job in parallel
      containers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    steps:
      - name:  Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
  
      - name:  Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          cache: 'npm'

      - name: Install Firebase Emulator Suite
        run: npm install -g firebase-tools@9.20.0

      - name:  Install Dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: ✅ E2E Tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4
        with:
          install: false
          start: |
            npm run e2e:firebase
            npm run e2e
          wait-on: http://localhost:4200
          wait-on-timeout: 120
          working-directory: apps/e2e
          record: true
          parallel: true
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: '${{ secrets.NX_FIREBASE_TOKEN }}'
```

And the result is like this [result e2e test on GitHub Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beU8t.png)

```
✓ should go to My Cards page (5043ms)
✓ should open Paint Point modal (3831ms)
✓ should open Insight modal (3323ms)
✓ should open Idea modal (2591ms)
(Attempt 1 of 3) should go to My Cards page
✓ should go to My Cards page (2328ms)
✓ should open Paint Point modal (1978ms)
✓ should open Insight modal (2302ms)
✓ should open Idea modal (2245ms)
✓ should create Paint Point card (4321ms)
(Attempt 1 of 3) should create Paint Point card
✓ should create Insight card (7147ms)
✓ should create Idea card (8727ms)
✓ should create Paint Point card (13580ms)
✓ should show modal from header create button (7298ms)
```

Do I miss a GitHub workflow configuration here?

Comment: What do your scripts `npm run e2e:firebase` and `npm run e2e` do? That may be the reason.

Comment: @jjhelguero I just start firbase and run e2e `"e2e": "npx nx run triniti-e2e:e2e"` and
    `"e2e:firebase": "firebase emulators:start --import=libs/data/export  --project=triniti-test"`

Comment: Hey could you find a solution for this problem? I also have the same issue now.. Also did you add `baseUrl` somewhere in the config?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you will need to split the workflow into 2 jobs as  [describe here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/github-actions#Install-Job).

Also you would need to make sure you are using their container image as mentioned [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Py9J.png)